# Can an android app send data packets to other phones?

Tags: android, communication

I'm trying to figure out if this is even possible:

I'm interested in writing a simple game that could be played in a peer-to-peer setup, rather than having to go through some intermediary server.  I was thinking of using something similar to how SMS works, but I don't know if those routines are accessible.

From what I understand, SMS is just a data packet with a specific structure, and on a certain port, that gets sent to a phone number as the unique identifier, rather than an IP Address.  If that is the case, is it possible to use similar routines to what SMS uses in order to send messages to another phone, but in such a way that SMS will not pick it up, and if the app that would understand that packet is not running, then the data would just get ignored?

Comment: Will phones be in close proximity?  Then use bluetooth if they are, otherwise you will need some sort of service server.  SMS is okay but not real time enough and limited

Comment: @JPM no.  My intent is to do something similar to a desktop application that can function as a standalone server and allow other programs to connect to it via IP.  Each phone connected through 3/4G technically has an IP address.  I'm looking into the possibility of determining a phone's IP address based solely on the phone number.

Comment: Not sure you can do that but its worth a shot I was able to setup a socket service using ATT phones and then communicated to it from a proprietary device to the phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write Apps that send SMS and receive SMS. Some things to keep in mind:

- SMS tend to be expensive, especially when compared to IP traffic.
- The user must grant the permission to send and read SMS to the app. He probably won't do, beacuse he knows it's expensive.
- Even if the users contract offers a SMS flat rate, providers may limit the actual number of SMS being sent or forbid automated, high-traffic usage.
- SMS might be much slower than IP packets.
- If a user tries to play with someone who hasn't installed the App, that poor person will have his SMS inbox flooded with those SMS.

So it's mostly a bad idea to use SMS for that purpose. Some alternatives if the users are close enouth to each other:

- Use bluetooth.
- Use Wifi (Most android phones won't allow ad-hoc connections, but some phones can act as acces points so that others can connect to it).
- Maybe: Use NFC (only some of the newest phones have this, and I don't know if you can use NFC that way).
- Use P2P over internet (which requires at least one provider to allow incoming connections on their network with a public IP, e.g. no internal NAT).
- Use a server that handles the traffic between phones.

Comment: So is SMS a different service and/or protocol from standard TCP traffic?  Is there any way that you can get a phone's IP address based solely on their phone number?

Comment: Correct, both are different. Old mobile phones support some kind of SMS protocol, but do not have a TCP stack. A recent smartphone can have both, but still many smartphones are not connected to the internet all the time. Only when the phone has an internet connection, it has an IP adress (which usually changes on each reconnect) so there is no way to map phone numbers to ip adresses.